# Unable to read firebase firestore collections from github workflows

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

```
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

      
jobs:
  read_firestore:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Check out code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Set up Node.js
        uses: actions/setup-node@v2
        with:
          node-version: '16.x'

      - name: Check Node.js and npm
        run: |
            node --version
            npm --version
            npx --version
      - name: Update Firebase CLI
        run: |
           npm install -g firebase-tools@latest
      - name: Show PATH
        run: echo $PATH
         

      - name: Restore Firestore Service Account Key
        run: echo "${{ secrets.FIRESTORE_SA_KEY }}" > firestore-service-account.json

      

      - name: Authenticate with Firestore
        run: |
          export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="$PWD/firestore-service-account.json"
        env:
          GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS: $PWD/firestore-service-account.json

      - name: Read Firestore Database
        run: |
          # Use the Firebase CLI to list documents from a Firestore collection
          firebase firestore:export --collection=users1 firestore-data.json
        working-directory: ${{ github.workspace }}

      - name: Upload Firestore Data
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: firestore-data
          path: firestore-data.json
```